# What is a reason to use warnings instead of print?

Tags: python, warnings

I wonder what is the advantage of using `warnings.warn` over using just `print` and why should I use it.

Not only the code is a bit more messy, but also the `warnings.warn`'s output:

```
/path/to/script/script.py:42: UserWarning: Warning message.
  warn("Warning message.", stacklevel=1)
```

I just don't see a need to print a script's path or a code fragment with the desired message.

Are my thoughts relevant, or there are some qualities of `warnings.warn` I'm blind to?
Or maybe, there are some other better ways to handle warnings?

Answer (score 0):

**warnings.warn** is different from **print**.

It could show different kind of Warnings: [Categories](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warning-categories)

These warnings could be filtered: [enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter)

So Warnings are very configurable, could be printed (stderr), do nothing, or thrown an Exception.

**Logging** is another thing completely different, I would say is more useful for a common application, to create logs in a file or just show them: [Logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)